# Optimise this function -- numpy broadcasting issue

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function `contains` that check for a given 2D array `u` if the box [min,max] contains each row of `u`. I need it to reshape `u` if needed, but the number of values of `u` will always be a multiple of `d` (can be zero);

I'm using the following snippet of code. This function run thousands of time. Can faster code be produced ? If you think so, any tips on how to ?

```
import numpy as np

def contains(u, min, max, dim, strict = True):
    u = np.array(u).reshape(-1 ,dim)
    if strict:
        return np.all((u > min) & (u < max), axis=1)
    else:
        return np.all((u >= min) & (u <= max), axis=1)

# Usage examples : 
d = 4
min = np.random.uniform(size=d)*1/2
max = np.random.uniform(size=d)*1/2+1/2
u1 = np.random.uniform(size=d)
u2 = np.random.uniform(size=(100,d))
u3 = u2[np.repeat(False,100)]

contains(u1,min,max,d) # should return a boolean array of shape (1,)
contains(u2,min,max,d) # shape (100,)
contains(u3,min,max,d) # shape (0,)
```

Comment: can the multiple calls of this function can be combined?

Comment: Some already are :/ But effectively, some are'nt. I'll look into this. E.g with broadcstable min/max parameters ?

Comment: have you looked into [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/)

Comment: Note that requests for improvement of working code are usually more welcome on [codereview.se]; here on Stack Overflow, we focus on programs that have specific, narrow, well-known problems with them. "X is too slow" *can* be specific and narrow, but only if you know what specific function call your problem is coming from, and already have knowledge that it *can*, definitely and without question, be improved.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, speed improvement questions are routine on SO - at least with the `[numpy]` tag.   There aren't as many `numpy` eyes on CR.  CR also tends to be pickier about the completeness of the code and examples.  SO solutions tend to focus on better whole-array operations, and compiling tools like `numba` and `cython`.  CR solutions tend to focus on style and organization.

Comment: What's different about those `contains` calls?  Different min, max paramters?  In numpy we usually get the best speedup by operating on whole arrays or with higher dumensions.  Tweaking any one call doesn't make big gains.

Answer (score 3):

(**EDITED**: to fix the timing measurement issue raised by @max9111 in the comments, and to include a `numexpr`-modified solution).

The bottleneck would eventually be within the `np.all()` call.
This could be sped up with Numba like the following:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def contains_nb(arr, a_arr, b_arr):
    m = a_arr.size
    arr = arr.reshape(-1, m)
    n = arr.shape[0]
    result = np.ones(n, dtype=np.bool8)
    for i in range(n):       
        for j in range(m):
            if not a_arr[j] < arr[i, j] < b_arr[j]:
                result[i] = False
                break
    return result
```

This is compared to the NumPy solution:

```
import numpy as np


def contains_np(arr, a_arr, b_arr):
    m = a_arr.size
    arr = arr.reshape(-1, m)
    return np.all((arr >= a_arr) & (arr <= b_arr), axis=1)
```

which I simplified a bit over your approach (I have omitted `dim` and `strict` parameters, since `dim` is redundant, as it can be inferred from `a_arr` or `b_arr` sizes, while the `strict` parameter does not add much to the solution, but it can be easily reintroduced).
I also assume that the input is already always a NumPy array.

Also, the NumPy solution could be modified to use `numexpr`, which leads to a third approach. This will have some calling overhead, but could speed up the computations, e.g.:

```
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne


def contains_ne(arr, a_arr, b_arr):
    m = a_arr.size
    arr = arr.reshape(-1, m)
    result = ne.evaluate('(arr >= a_arr) & (arr <= b_arr)')
    return np.all(result, axis=1)
```

The following benchmarks can be obtained:

[image: bm]

This show that the Numba solution is consistently the fastest.
On the contrary, the use of `numexpr` seems to be non-beneficial for the range of parameters explored.

(full benchmark available [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/145w5N_X2lXHIqA--7pIf-Rq6EFfQtvDI))

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark. However, the values of `n` i have tend, regarding your benchmark, to require the numpy version !

Comment: Your timings have an issue. Using default values like this `contains_nb(arr, a_arr=A, b_arr=B)` and calling the function like `contains_nb(input_arr)` leads to a recompilation on every call. This has a overhead of about 270µs per call, which completely dominates the timings for small input sizes. It would be around 1µs if you provide the input explicitly.

Comment: @max9111 thanks for spotting this, I have it fixed in the edits.

Comment: @Irnv Look at the updated benchmarks. Perhaps you may want to reconsider the Numba-based approach. Essentially, the code does not change, it is just the way it is being benchmarked.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to speed, read more [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/speed-up-your-algorithms-part-2-numba-293e554c5cc1)

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def contains(u, min, max, dim, strict = True):
    u = np.array(u).reshape(-1 ,dim)
    if strict:
        return np.all((u > min) & (u < max), axis=1)
    else:
        return np.all((u >= min) & (u <= max), axis=1)
```